# Why doesn't a '==' comparison on a column work in Spark SQL?

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, comparison

I have a simple spark statement but it seems to return `false` contrary to expected result of `true`:

```
spark.sql("SELECT 1 AS a").withColumn("b", lit($"a" == 1)).show
+---+-----+
|  a|    b|
+---+-----+
|  1|false|
+---+-----+
```

I've tried `$"a" == lit(1)` and `$"a".equals(1)` etc. but all return `false`.
A statement of `$"a" >= 1` returns `true` so why not `$"a" == 1`?

Comment: Aha.. it might have been better to include the language you were coding in as part of the question. It also would have better had i asked that. I'll delete my answer.

Comment: @tarik it is in the title, tags, in the first sentence and has an example.

Comment: triple equal is very useful, but not something in the Spark SQL syntax (https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/index.html). It is in the language which you are using to call the Spark SQL, which you can invoke using Scala, Python, etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scala has defined === operator that works as a type-safe equals operator, very similar to the operator in javascript. Spark framework defines the equalTo method in Column class. equalTo returns a new Column object that has the result of comparing two column values. The method equalTo is used by === operator to compare column values. Operator == uses the equals method that checks if both the objects being compared are referencing to the same object. Have a look at the spark API docs for these methods in column class:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html#equalTo-java.lang.Object-
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html#equals-java.lang.Object-

Answer (score 0):

Using a triple '=' solved my problem.

```
spark.sql("SELECT 1 AS a").withColumn("b", $"a" === 1).show
+---+----+
|  a|   b|
+---+----+
|  1|true|
+---+----+
```